# Pandas rolling sum to filter signals

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe where I am creating a column named Signal when certain conditions are met, resulting in something like:

```
Index    Data      ... Signal
1        ...             0
2        ...             1
3        ...             1
4        ...             0
5        ...             1
6        ...             0
7        ...             1
8        ...             1
```

Now, I want to filter my signal column in such a way I only get a signal if the signal conditions are met, but also if no signal was triggered for the previous N rows. For example, for N=3:

```
Index    Data      ... Signal    Filtered_Signal
1        ...             0            0
2        ...             1            1
3        ...             1            0
4        ...             0            0
5        ...             1            0
6        ...             0            0
7        ...             1            1
8        ...             1            0
```

So my attempt was performing a rolling window of size N, apply sum(), shift(1) to avoid including the active row in that sum, and then check if that sum is greater than zero, which would mean there was at least a signal in previous N rows:

```
df['Signal'] = np.where((df['data']>=2), 1, 0) # As an example
df['Filtered_Signal'] = df.Signal.rolling(N, min_periods=1).sum().shift(-1)
signals = df.loc[(df['Signal']==1) & (df['Filtered_Signal']<=1)]
```

Nevertheless, it doesn't work as I expected. Signal column gets (for my use case) almost 900 entries with a 1, but then, for N=10, I get only 1 entry with a 1 in Filtered_Signal. It seems rolling doesn't work dynamically, so it directly removes all the Signal entries not separated more than N rows from another Signal, resulting in almost all of them being removed.

I could iterate the dataframe and perform this filtering in an old-fashioned way, but my question is: is there a pythonic (on pandanic) way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your problem is the way you have created 'Filtered Signal'. It seems Filtered Signal using your code can have values much bigger then 1 and it doesn't seem to be what you were looking for. If I understood your question correctly then the following code works just fine:

```
df['Filtered Signal']=np.where((df.Signal.rolling(N+1,min_periods=1).sum()==1) & (df.Signal.rolling(1,min_periods=1).sum()==1),1,0)
signals=df.loc[(df['Signal']==1) & (df['Filtered Signal']<=1)]
```

Just Replace your second line you posted with the way I have created filtered Signal.

Please note that I have deleted the shift, and used N+1 window instead.

If the solution was helpful, please like this answer :).

Comment: I still do not understand where the difference is, but it does work. Thanks!